# Why are dynamic frameworks like this not scalable?

Tags: php, dynamic, frameworks, scalability, scaling

I've always had a thing for dynamic code. Code that's really easy to add cool new features to, without doing much work. For that reason, I build lots of dynamic frameworks and use them in my projects. Some are small, some are big.

As an example, I built a small custom error reporting framework that I still use in almost all of my projects today.

Here's a quick example of how it works:

**error_reportLibrary.php** - This is where all the magic happens. The class and all the methods sits here. This is the file included when the framework is needed.

**error_reportConfig.php** - This is where my configuration goes (error types, ect). Here's an example of this file, which shall give you a pretty good explanation of how the small framework works:

(**the comments in the code should explain what each element does as a setting**)

```
# ------ Main Settings ---------

$error_handlingSettings['errorStat']=true;//set this to false, and I wont display any errors. I don't care what the other errorTypes have to say.
$error_handlingSettings['default_highlight_color']="red";//this is the default highlight color that will be used if no color is defined for a specific errorType

# ------ Open API -------
$error_handlingSettings['open_api']['status']=true;//set this to true and I'll show errors for the Open API
$error_handlingSettings['open_api']['highlight_color']="#0ff";//shall I highlight any errors that occur for this specific type? if so, set this to a color.
$error_handlingSettings['open_api']['onRemoteAddr']=true;//shall I display errors to specific IP addresses?
$error_handlingSettings['open_api']['remote_addr'][]="86.8.168.228";//so I will show to this IP
$error_handlingSettings['open_api']['remote_addr'][]="127.0.0.1";//and this IP

# ------ SQL Core -------
$error_handlingSettings['sql_core']['status']=true;//set this to true and I'll show errors for the SQL Core
$error_handlingSettings['sql_core']['highlight_color']="orange";//shall I highlight any errors that occur for this specific type? if so, set this to a color.
$error_handlingSettings['sql_core']['onRemoteAddr']=true;//shall I display errors to specific IP addresses?
$error_handlingSettings['sql_core']['remote_addr'][]="86.8.168.228";//so I will show to this IP
$error_handlingSettings['sql_core']['remote_addr'][]="127.0.0.1";//and this IP
```

So as you can probably tell, each error type is simply a different part of the project I'm using the framework on (for example, SQL Core is the database framework I use. So if any db query issues occur, this errorType will be looked at when printing errors).

So for printing errors, this is the syntax:

```
errorModule::doError("errorType","error messege");
```

As you can see, there are some extra little things I can do. Like display to certain IP addresses and highlight the error text, which I can confidently say: will not affect the scalability of the framework.

Remember, the above is just an example of the dynamic frameworks I create/use in my projects.

Now, to the question(almost): I've been told by a few of my colleges that dynamic frameworks like the above are terrible when it comes to scalability. Regardless of the fact that they are very maintainable. So if I used the above framework on a web app that got 1M+ requests a day, it would totally screw up...

Now I'm not apposing against their opinion (actually....) but I would like to know why this is? Why is a dynamic framework like the above considered bad for scalability?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the point when creating a 'dynamic framework.'

A lot of my earlier PHP code functioned sort of like this; a class with a bunch of methods and maybe a construct method that set up a state, using globals to track configuration in arrays. These all used a lot of memory compared to a wholly OOP approach; and while yes less memory and faster than an 'off the shelf' solution; nothing compared to the way I design frameworks now.

It doesn't appear you are taking advantage of things like interfaces, abstract classes, both class and interface inheritance and so forth. These types of frameworks do scale because the original code base is so small and take advantage of specific OOP functionality (like PHP 5.x's magic methods.)

Multiply a script that you felt was fast enough running on server that's not taxed very much by say 100 and, you've got problems; and you're running out of memory, hitting pages outs; and things will crawl to the point you're forced to reboot/throw more resources at the server.

Why? Poorly written procedural code that tries to act OOP, even tries to look like it, is just wrapping up old habits in a new package.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is slow and clunky in general. It's high-level, which means each line carries "baggage". It's common that a single line of PHP code will convert to a slew of low-level instructions.

You can still scale 'dynamic' frameworks that rely heavily upon PHP's underlying system, and don't waste a lot of time or memory with high-level abstractions.

In my opinion, large, "convenient" frameworks often cause more problems than they solve once shit hits the fan in a production environment. My favorite teachers always reminded me to K.I.S.S. -- Keep It Simple Stupid.

Of course, If you want truly scalable performance you may want to compile your php with [hiphop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) or write your application in a compiled language like C++ or D.